# __import__ missing from Python __builtins__ (when in Django Shell)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I hope this isn't too dumb of a question :-(  but why isn't `__import__` included in `inspect.getmembers(__builtins__)`?

Here's what I get when I try to print the builtins:

```
>>> sorted([name for (name,obj) in inspect.getmembers(__builtins__)])
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
```

**Update:**

Actually I was in the Django 1.6 shell when I ran that.  (Python 2.7).

Running it in Python 2.7 alone does include `__import__`.  What could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> [27.3. `__builtin__` — Built-in objects](http://docs.python.org/library/__builtin__.html)
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** Most modules have the name `__builtins__` (note the `'s'`) made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this modules’s [sic] **`__dict__`** attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

In your case, it looks like the `__builtins__` you are looking at is the dictionary not the module (`__builtin__.__dict__` rather than `__builtin__`).  So `inspect.getmembers` is returning the attributes of the dict class rather than the keys.  Instead you might want something like the following:

```
if isinstance(__builtins__, dict):
    names = sorted(__builtins__)
else:
    names = sorted(name for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(__builtins__))
```

Or alternatively:

```
import __builtin__
names = sorted(name for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(__builtin__))
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize I was in the django shell when I posted my original question.  It is working in regular python 2.7.

Comment: This explanation should still be valid.